# JSF ElResolver Returns wrong type with generics

Tags: jsf-2

I try to set the values of a selectManyCheckbox to my testBean backing bean.
If I use a property of type `List<String>` instead of `Attributed<List<String>>` it works perfectly. It is the workaround I'm using currently.

But on my backing bean I have a generic object which contains the List.
The `javax.el.BeanELResolver` resolve this to an Object. Which is correct due to Type erasure.

I tried to implement a custom ElResolver. But I should know to which type to convert the object to. It isn't obviously always a List. I have the information in the xhtml pages. So I hoped I could pass some child element which would contain the information, but could not find a way to access the child element from the ElResolver.

A Custom converted does not work either as it converts selectItems, not the List.

Here is the simplest form

```
<h:form>
    <p:selectManyCheckbox  value="#{testBean.attributed.value}" >  
        <f:selectItems value="#{testBean.selection}" />  
    </p:selectManyCheckbox>         
    <p:commandButton action="@{testBean.execute}" value="do it" />
</h:form>
```

and the bean

```
private Attributed<List<String>> attributed = new Attributed<>();

public Map<String, String> getSelection() {
    return ImmutableMap.<String, String> of("key1", "value1", "key2", "value2");
}

public static class Attributed<T> {
    private T value;

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public Attributed<List<String>> getAttributed() {
    return attributed;
}

public void setAttributed(Attributed<List<String>> attributed) {
    this.attributed = attributed;
}
```

So the question is:
Is there a way to set the value to `testBean.attributed.value` directly and with the correct type. 
Is it possible by defining a custom ElResolver, or are there other way to do it?

Comment: How does that `Attributed` make sense in the model? I'd say, your whole problem is caused by using a wrong model in the first place. You should create exactly the model which the view expects. Map if necessary afterwards in bean's action method or so.

Comment: The obvious solutions are not always the one I think about :) Thanks for the input